# Flash multidimensional array of movieclips

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-2, fractions

Programming an educational program with fractions, you can touch a part of a fraction on a digiboard (or pc screen) that becomes colored/active. Touch or click it a second time and it becomes white/unactive again. And so on...

To reset a fraction with all of its colored parts to white I want to press a single button once that's calling the function resetFraction. Please take a look at the code below, it seems to go wrong at the two-dimensional array with movieclips - no change from colored to a white part. All arrays containing names of movieclips:

```
//array with fractions containing the (real) movieclips of parts
//mc_frac1 has one part, mc_frac2 has two parts, and so on
var fractionAr : Array = new Array(mc_frac1, mc_frac2, mc_frac3, mc_frac4, mc_frac5);

//array with max-index for partAr, see below
var maxPart : Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);

//array with parts, 2 dimensional with a variable index per fraction
var partAr : Array = new Array(
        new Array(mc_part1_1),
        new Array(mc_part2_1, mc_part2_2),
        new Array(mc_part3_1, mc_part3_2, mc_part3_3),
        new Array(mc_part4_1, mc_part4_2, mc_part4_3, mc_part4_4),
        new Array(mc_part5_1, mc_part5_2, mc_part5_3, mc_part5_4, mc_part5_5));

//put all parts back to 'untouched' (color white)
function resetFraction(var FracNum : Number) {
var p : Number = FracNum;
for (var i = 0; i < maxPart[p]; i++) {
    fractionAr[p-1].partAr[p-1][i].gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

This code below is split up in portions to see where it goes wrong:

```
p = 4;
mc_frac4.mc_part4_2.gotoAndStop(1); //works
fracAr[p-1].mc_part4_2.gotoAndStop(1); //works
//but
fracAr[p-1].partAr[3][1].gotoAndStop(1); //does nothing
```

The two-dimensional array seems to be the problem.

Anyone can help me? It saves a lot of code to realise this with one function.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm out!

Instead of the dot (.) I use the array acces operators ([ ]) and quotes (" ") in the partAr array:

```
var partAr : Array =
         new Array(
         new Array("mc_part1_1"),
         new Array("mc_part2_1", "mc_part2_2"), and so on...
```

while the fourth line in the function becomes this:

```
function resetFraction(var FracNum : Number) {
var p : Number = FracNum;
for (var i = 0; i < maxPart[p]; i++) {
    fractionAr[p-1][partAr[p-1][i]].gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Simple, isn't it?